# Is possible to change "lineColor" in 3d charts?

Tags: highcharts

I want to change color on yAxis in 3d chart, for example this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/

if I add, in the Yaxis this:

```
   lineColor: '#ff0000'
```

but the color doesn't change. Why?

Comment: Color of what exactly? There is no line when you apply `lineColor`, it's a scatter.

Comment: ah ok now i understand... i want to have an Yaxis with more colurs. lineColor is impossible to apply, so i have try to add a colour on frame (on side), but the only way that i know is to add colours with linearGradient... but i don't want a Gradient.    Maybe the only way is to add more rect elements ? give me a suggestion

Comment: Why don't you change the color of the side, bottom or back in `options3d`? Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/uvubopow/

Comment: yes it is, but i want more colors, but not with gradient.. is there a way to do what i want to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the color of side in `options3d.frame` to change the yAxis color:

```
frame: {
    bottom: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)' },
    back: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)' },
    side: { size: 1, color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.15)' }
}
```

Then you could use `alternateGridColor` to have two colors and also play with the opacity of bottom, back and side. Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvubopow/1/)

**EDIT:**

You can also use `plotBands` like this:

```
plotBands: [{
     color: '#FCFFC5',
     from: 0,
     to: 2.5
}]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uvubopow/2/)

Comment: but  with the alternateGridColor i can't set when a color start and end. Besides i don'want alternate colors...   :(  and is possible add two rect on "side" frame ? (two rects with different colors) ???

Comment: yes i'm trying, i think is good idea... thank you very much !

Comment: You are welcome. Please check my answer as the correct answer. I saw your questions, you have not checked any of them as answered.

Comment: where i must to check ?